# TODO reminder constexpr

Tags: c++, constexpr

I saw a guy creating something like a static_assert that uses **DATE** to create a reminder of a TODO code section, I liked the idea so I tried to implement it, the problem cames when my compiler doesn't like my aproximation, it says:

1. Too complex constexpr function
2. Expression should have constant value

Im using Visual studio 2017 with c++17 features enabled, the keyword CONSTEXPR is a macro that subtitudes with constexpr if the compiler supports it

Code:

```
namespace private_TODO
{
CONSTEXPR bool is_digit(char c)
{
    return c <= '9' && c >= '0';
}

CONSTEXPR unsigned stoi_impl(const char* str, int rec = 0, int value = 0)
{
    return rec != 0 ?
        is_digit(*str) ?
        stoi_impl(str + 1, rec--, (*str - '0') + value * 10)
        : throw "Compile-time-error: not a digit"
        : value;
}

CONSTEXPR unsigned stoi(const char* str, int maxIter)
{
    return stoi_impl(str, maxIter);
}

CONSTEXPR unsigned year(const char* str)
{
    return stoi(str, 4);
}

CONSTEXPR bool str_cmp(const char* str, const char* str2, unsigned sz)
{
    return sz != 0 ?
        *str == *str2 ? str_cmp(str + 1, str2 + 1, --sz)
            : false
        : true;
}

CONSTEXPR unsigned month(const char* str)
{
    return str_cmp(str, "Jan", 3) ? 1 :
        str_cmp(str, "Feb", 3) ? 2 :
        str_cmp(str, "Mar", 3) ? 3 :
        str_cmp(str, "Apr", 3) ? 4 :
        str_cmp(str, "May", 3) ? 5 :
        str_cmp(str, "Jun", 3) ? 6 :
        str_cmp(str, "Jul", 3) ? 7 :
        str_cmp(str, "Aug", 3) ? 8 :
        str_cmp(str, "Set", 3) ? 9 :
        str_cmp(str, "Oct", 3) ? 10 :
        str_cmp(str, "Nov", 3) ? 11 :
        str_cmp(str, "Dec", 3) ? 12 :
        throw "Compile-time error: Not a month!";
}

CONSTEXPR unsigned day(const char* str)
{
    return stoi(str, 2);
}

CONSTEXPR unsigned str_size(const char* str, unsigned value = 0)
{
    return *str != 0 ?
        str_size(str++, value++)
        : value;
}

CONSTEXPR unsigned total(const char* str)
{
    return (str_size(str) == 11 && str[3] == ' ' && str[6] == ' ') ?
        year(str + 7) * 512 + month(str) * 32 + day(str + 4)
        : throw "invalid string";
}
}

#define TODO(DATE, MESSAGE)\
static_assert(::private_TODO::total(__DATE__) < ::private_TODO::total(DATE), MESSAGE)
void test()
{
    TODO("NOV 16 2017", "THIS SHOULD THROW"); //11/16/17 is when I tested
}
```

I don't understand why says Expression should have constant value, cause everything I think is constant, and yes they are complex functions, I wish if someone could help me to reduce de complexity of this functions

EDIT: One of the errors came from str_size it says that cannot evaluate it as constant

I finally made it using string_view class

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
using namespace std::string_view_literals;
/* TODO reminders */
namespace private_TODO
{
CONSTEXPR bool is_digit(char c)
{
    return c <= '9' && c >= '0';
}


CONSTEXPR unsigned stoi_impl(const std::string_view& str, int value = 0)
{
    return str.size() != 0 ?
        is_digit(str[0]) ?
        stoi_impl(str.substr(1, str.size() - 1), (str[0] - '0') + value * 10)
        : throw "Compile-time-error: not a digit"
        : value;
}

CONSTEXPR unsigned stoi(const std::string_view& str)
{
    return stoi_impl(str);
}

CONSTEXPR bool str_cmp(const std::string_view& str, const std::string_view& str2, unsigned sz = 0)
{
    return sz != str.size() ?
        str[sz] == str2[sz] ?
        str_cmp(str, str2, ++sz)
        : false
        : true;
}

CONSTEXPR unsigned month(const std::string_view& str)
{
    return 
        str_cmp(str, "Jan"sv) ? 1 :
        str_cmp(str, "Feb"sv) ? 2 :
        str_cmp(str, "Mar"sv) ? 3 :
        str_cmp(str, "Apr"sv) ? 4 :
        str_cmp(str, "May"sv) ? 5 :
        str_cmp(str, "Jun"sv) ? 6 :
        str_cmp(str, "Jul"sv) ? 7 :
        str_cmp(str, "Aug"sv) ? 8 :
        str_cmp(str, "Set"sv) ? 9 :
        str_cmp(str, "Oct"sv) ? 10 :
        str_cmp(str, "Nov"sv) ? 11 :
        str_cmp(str, "Dec"sv) ? 12 :
        throw "Compile-time error: Not a month!";
}

CONSTEXPR unsigned total(const std::string_view& str)
{
    return (str.size() == 11 && str[3] == ' ' && str[6] == ' ') ?
        stoi(str.substr(7, 4)) * 512 + month(str.substr(0, 3)) * 32 + stoi(str.substr(4, 2))
        : throw "invalid string";
}
}
#define TODO(DATE, MESSAGE)\
static_assert(::private_TODO::total(std::string_view(__DATE__, 11)) < ::private_TODO::total(DATE ## sv), MESSAGE)
```

Comment: please give the precise compiler error message, including the line(s) of code for which it complains.

Comment: `str_cmp(str + 1, str2 + 1, sz--)` seems wrong. Shouldn't it rather be `str_cmp(str + 1, str2 + 1, --sz)` ?

Comment: --sz Correction done, thank you

Comment: Note that if you are using a compiler with c++17 support (or even c++14), you don't need to jump through all those hoops to be constexpr-compliant.  (i.e. you can use `if` instead of ternaries, and loops instead of recursion)

Comment: The problem is that I have to learn how to use c++17 features and I have to support c++14, but it would be a great idea to have a c++17 functions and by macros enable them instead the c++14 ones

Comment: I have so many questions about why this code exists. So many.

Comment: It's a way that make that todo statements doesn't remain forgotten in a comment

Comment: A way to debug this is to temporarily remove the constexpr attribute and execute the code !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `constexpr` must evaluate after a **finite** number of recursions. Your functions

```
constexpr bool str_cmp(const char* str, const char* str2, unsigned sz)
{
    return sz != 0 ?
        *str == *str2 ? str_cmp(str + 1, str2 + 1, sz--)
            : false
        : true;
}

constexpr unsigned str_size(const char* str, unsigned value = 0)
{
    return *str != 0 ?
        str_size(str++, value++)
        : value;
}
```

don't. Rather they constitute infinite recursion and out-of-bounds access. The point is that the return values, i.e. the values passed to the recursion, of

```
sz--
str++
value++
```

are the same as the input. Correct is

```
constexpr bool str_cmp(const char* str1, const char* str2, unsigned size)
{
  return size==0 || (*str1 == *str2 && str_cmp(++str1,++str2,--size));
}

constexpr unsigned str_size(const char* str, unsigned value = 0)
{
  return *str? str_size(++str,++value) : value;
}
```

This may not be the only error in your code, though.

Comment: Missing `*` in your `str_size()`.   As is, it is infinitely recursive too.